# Erro ao tentar realizar deploy, repository access denied

Tags: php, laravel, linux, deploy, bitbucket

Estou desenvolvendo em laravel, e não consigo usar o deployer parava fazer o deploy pro nosso server na amazon,

nosso deploy.php está assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e estamos recebendo este erro, notem que pareço estar no repositorio certo ...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e minha SSH está no bitbucket

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que + falta pra funcionar ?

Comment: Seu usuário é dono ou tem permissão de leitura e escrita nesse repositório?

Comment: Sim, é admin...

Comment: Essa máquina tem apenas uma chave SSH ou mais? Sua conta no bitbucket tem uma chave SSH só né?

Comment: No caminho /.ssh/id_rsa.pub só tem 1 chave SSH, no bitbucket tem uma chave ssh só tambêm